# Delphi 11, FMX, open the file knowing its Path

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I am writing a small application for Android in Delphi. Multiple forms with data and the ability to attach files or take a photo. After filling in the content, I need to send it to the server. All this is already working, I can take a photo and send it.

But, I also need to be able to select any file on the device itself, view it at any time, and send it. These can be photos, videos or documents. The file selection dialog opens, the selection event is also triggered and I get 1 or more selected files (Uris). And then I need to register the name and path of the file in the table (in order to open or forward it in the future), and then I can't move from my place. I get the file name, but the path returns only the form "\image:123456" or "\document:image\img1234.jpg ".

As far as I understand, Android does not like to give out (turnouts and passwords) the real paths where the files lie. Rather, there are like examples of how you can get a path through `Cursor`, but I can't find examples in Delphi.

Does someone have a similar task, and can share an example of the code for opening and receiving the contents of the file (for transmission over https in base64 format)?

The function of getting the file name:

```
function GetFileName(Uri: Jnet_Uri): String;
var
  Cur: JCursor;
begin
  Result := '';
  Cur := TAndroidHelper.Context.getContentResolver().query(Uri, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil);
  try
    if (Cur <> nil) then
      if Cur.moveToFirst then
        Result := JStringToString(Cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(TJOpenableColumns.JavaClass.DISPLAY_NAME)));
  finally
    Cur.close;
  end;
end;
```

Selecting the file(s):

```
procedure TDM.GetFileBrowser(ReqCode: Integer);
var
  Intent: JIntent;
  FName: String;
  F: JFile;
begin
  Intent := TJIntent.Create;

  Intent.setType(StringToJString('*/*'));
  Intent.setAction(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
  Intent.putExtra(TJIntent.JavaClass.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE,true);

  TMessageManager.DefaultManager.SubscribeToMessage(TMessageResultNotification,
    procedure(const Sender   : TObject;
              const aMessage : TMessage)
          var msgRES : TMessageResultNotification;
              i: Integer;
        begin
              msgRES:= TMessageResultNotification(aMessage);

              if msgRES.RequestCode=ReqCode then
                 if (msgRES.ResultCode=TJActivity.JavaClass.RESULT_OK) then
                 begin

                     URIfileTrn := msgRES.Value.getData(); //URI sing file selez

                     if URIfileTrn = nil then //multiselez
                     begin
                        ClipDataF := msgRES.Value.getClipData;
                        for i := 0 to ClipDataF.getItemCount-1 do
                        begin
                          URIfileTrn := ClipDataF.getItemAt(i).getUri;
                          FName := GetFileName(URIfileTrn);
                          F := TJFile.JavaClass.init(URIfileTrn.getPath);
                          //F.getAbsolutePath;
                          if FName <> '' then
                            case ReqCode of
                              1000: SaveFile(FName, JStringToString(F.getAbsolutePath));
                              2000: SaveSFile(FName, JStringToString(F.getAbsolutePath));
                            end;
                        end;
                     end
                     else begin
                       FName := GetFileName(URIfileTrn);
                       F := TJFile.JavaClass.init(URIfileTrn.getPath);
                       if FName <> '' then
                         case ReqCode of
                            1000: SaveFile(FName, JStringToString(F.getAbsolutePath));
                            2000: SaveSFile(FName, JStringToString(F.getAbsolutePath));
                         end;
                     end;

                     URIfileTrn := nil;
                 end;
        end);

  TAndroidHelper.Activity.startActivityForResult(Intent, ReqCode);
end;
```

Opening a file:

```
procedure TDM.openFile(FileName: String); (* PdfDosyasiSec *)
var
  ExtFile: string;
  mime: JMimeTypeMap;
  ExtToMime: JString;
  Intent: JIntent;
  pathN:string;
  Uri: Jnet_Uri;
  LAuthority: JString;
begin
  if DM.qFiles.IsEmpty then
    Exit;
  if not TFile.Exists(FileName) then
  begin
      TDialogService.MessageDialog('Файл не существует (возможно был удален или перемещен). Удалить запись о файле из таблицы?', System.UITypes.TMsgDlgType.mtInformation,
        [System.UITypes.TMsgDlgBtn.mbYes, System.UITypes.TMsgDlgBtn.mbNo],
        System.UITypes.TMsgDlgBtn.mbNo, 0,

      // Use an anonymous method to make sure the acknowledgment appears as expected.
      procedure(const AResult: TModalResult)
      begin
        case AResult of
          { Detect which button was pushed and show a different message }
          mrYES: begin
                  DM.qFiles.Delete;
                  Exit;
          end;
          mrNo: Exit;
        end;
      end);
  end;
  try
    ExtFile := AnsiLowerCase(StringReplace(TPath.GetExtension(FileName), '.', '',[]));
    mime := TJMimeTypeMap.JavaClass.getSingleton();
    ExtToMime := mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(StringToJString(ExtFile));
    LAuthority := StringToJString(JStringToString(TAndroidHelper.Context.getApplicationContext.getPackageName) + '.fileprovider');
    Uri := TJcontent_FileProvider.JavaClass.getUriForFile(TAndroidHelper.Context, LAuthority, TJFile.JavaClass.init(StringToJString(FileName)));
    Intent := TJIntent.Create;
    Intent.setFlags(TJIntent.JavaClass.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    Intent.setAction(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_VIEW);
    Intent.setDataAndType(Uri, ExtToMime);
    TAndroidHelper.Activity.startActivity(Intent);
  except
    ShowMessage('Невозможно открыть файл!');
  end
end;
android
```

I was trying to get the path to the files through the File `object.getAbsolutePath()` and `Cfile.getPath()`, but the result is the same.

Comment: You get a content scheme uri. Not a file path. Trying to get the path part of an uri makes no sense as you have seen. Use the uri to handle the file.

Comment: Your openFile() method uses FileProvider to get an uri for a false path in order to use ACTION_VIEW. Better use the original content scheme uri right away. You can clean up a lot of wrong code then too.